# Mostrar completo un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un programa que retorna un array con mas de 100 números. En consola (node) me sale lo siguiente:

```
[1,
,2
,3
,4
,5
,6
,7
...
,20
,21
,22
... 88 more items ]
```

¿Cómo hago para que los items salgan uno al lado del otro?

¿Soy claro con la pregunta?

Gracias por comentar.

Comment: es decir que salga de forma horizontal y no de forma vertical cierto?

Comment: exacto, o como puedo darle "formato" a mis salidas, que en este caso las hago con un console.log()

Comment: Iteras sobre el array y montas el string como quieras que te aparezca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes implementar tu propia función logger que devuelva las trazas como tu quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
const logger = ( pagination ) => ( arr ) => {
  if (arr.length < pagination){
    console.log (arr);
  }
  else {
    while ( arr.length >= pagination) {
        console.log(arr.slice(0, pagination));
        arr = arr.slice(pagination, arr.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Utilizando la currificación, puedes establecer el primer parámetro, pagination, al principio de la ejecución del fichero, y después llamarla siempre que quieras para cualquier array.

```
const log = logger ( 2 );
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

log (array); 
// [1, 2]
// [3, 4]
// [5, 6]
```

Si no quieres utilizar currificación, basta con declarar la función así:

```
const logger = ( pagination, arr ) => {
  if (arr.length < pagination){
    console.log (arr);
  }
  else {
    while ( arr.length >= pagination) {
      console.log(arr.slice(0, pagination));
      arr = arr.slice(pagination, arr.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Y llamarla así:

```
logger(2,array);
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma de hacerlo es iterar sobre el array y manejas el string como mas te sirva.

```js
let arr = [
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10];

let string = '';
arr.forEach((e,i) => {
  if (i == 0){
   string += e
  } else {
   string += `, ${e}`
  }
})

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Llego tarde (¡más de un año!), pero me parece útil comentar que existe una respuesta más simple: usar el método `toString()` de la clase `Array`

```js
let arrayLargo= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

console.log(arrayLargo.toString());
```